# Transpilation when using Jest with Typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

When I launch my test suit with Jest in a Typescript project, I have this compilation error:

> TypeError:
>   /PATH/instant.ts:
>   Cannot read property 'some' of undefined

In my package.json, I have this Jest configuration:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/src/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
     "js"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageReporters": [
     "json",
     "html"
    ]
  }
```

Instant.ts:

```
export class Instant {

    constructor(private id: string,
                private name: string) {
    }

}
```

And instant.js:

```
export class Instant {
    constructor(id, name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
//# sourceMappingURL=instant.js.map
```

Comment: I think we need to see some code from `instant.ts`

Comment: @Fenton I updated my question

Comment: There is no `some` anywhere in your code.

Comment: I don’t have ‘some’ anywhere in my code

Answer (score 0):

I share my own Jest config whose works for me:

```
{
    preset: 'react-native',
    rootDir: '..',
    setupFiles: [
        '<rootDir>/configuration/jest.setup.js'
    ],
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        'ts',
        'tsx',
        'js'
    ],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js',
        '\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest'
    },
    testMatch: [
        '<rootDir>/__tests__/**/?(*.)+(spec|test).ts?(x)'
    ],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        '\\.snap$',
        '<rootDir>/node_modules/'
    ],
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        '<rootDir>/src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'
    ],
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
        '<rootDir>/__tests__/'
    ],
    coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/jest/coverage',
    coverageReporters: [
        'html',
        'text',
        'text-summary'
    ]
}
```